# django "__contains" and "__in" as a single query

Tags: python, django

I have a rather strange problem in Django, where I do not see how I could combine "__contains" and "__in" in a single statement.

So, here is my situation: I have a list of entries like so:

```
a = ["hgfjhgj89789jkbjk", "jhgjkhj89789jkhkjh", "jhgkjhkj89689gfghdfhg"]
```

and I would like to check this list against a queryset - which I would normally do like so:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all().filter(my_field__in=a)
```

However, in my situation, `my_field` does not exactly match the values in `a` and therefore, I am having to resort to `__contains` like so:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all().filter(my_field__contains=a[0])
```

..but then, my `a` has now 2000 entries, and I cannot run the above query 2000times - sounds silly.

So, how can I combine this "__contains" with "__in"?
Sorry if this is a daft question!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the case!

Comment: That question was sadly misnamed (fixed), but it is the exact same question with the exact same answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can't be done with one filter, but it could be done using Django's `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q()
for entry in a:
    query = query | Q(my_field__contains=entry)

queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(query)
```

[`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) let you do complex queries in one go - check out the docs for more examples.

Comment: Does this preserve the order of the values in `a`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The resulting queryset will be ordered by whatever ordering the database spits out.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `a`'s order is not preserved in the resulting queryset - if you know what I mean.. so if `a=[1,2,3]` the queryset spits out the results in a different order...Is there any way to preserve this order of `a` in the resulting queryset?

Comment: At the database level, you can only order by fields. So you could order the result by my_field - but you can't make all the ones that matched a[0] come first, then those that matched a[1], etc. You'd have to do that in Python afterwards.

Comment: ok Ben - understood :) Accepted your answer! Thanks a tonne!